# Coded UI result report in TFS 2015

Tags: coded-ui-tests, tfs-2015

I have a suite of tests that run with inputs from a .csv file from TFS on a remote desktop. 
If one of the rows fails it is still reported as passed in TFS but not if you open the .trx file. 
Is there any way to mark that test as failed in TFS if one row fails?

Edit: I'm using vNext to build.

Comment: Can you post one of your data driven tests so we can see how it handles the error.

Comment: What's the build system you are using with the Coded UI test? The new vNext or the old  XAML?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using vNext build, there is no way to mark that test as failed in TFS if one row fails.